# Error installation phpoffice/phpspreadsheet with composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.4, phpspreadsheet

I try to install a specific spreachsheet lib with this command:

composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.8.2 (because I have Php5 version)

I have this error :

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- symfony/symfony is locked to version v3.4.10 and an update of this package was not requested.

- Only one of these can be installed: symfony/twig-bundle[v3.4.26], symfony/symfony[v3.4.10]. symfony/symfony replaces symfony/twig-bundle and thus cannot coexist with it.

- symfony/twig-bundle is locked to version v3.4.26 and an update of this package was not requested.
```

my composer.json:

{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The "Symfony Standard Edition" distribution",
"autoload": {
"psr-4": {
"": "src/"
},
"classmap": [ "app/AppKernel.php", "app/AppCache.php" ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
"psr-4": { "AppBundle\Tests\": "tests/" },
"files": [ "vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/VarDumper/Resources/functions/dump.php" ]
},
"require": {
"php": ">=5.5.9",
"beberlei/doctrineextensions": "1.1.9",
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^1.3",
"doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
"incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
"paragonie/random_compat": "~1.3",
"phpseclib/phpseclib": "^2.0",
"ramsey/uuid": "^3.8",
"sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
"sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
"symfony/assetic-bundle": "^2.8",
"symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
"symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
"symfony/symfony": "3.4.10",
"symfony/translation": "^3.4",
"symfony/twig-bundle": "3.4.26",
"symfony/validator": "^3.4",
"theodo-evolution/legacy-wrapper-bundle": "^1.2",
"theodo-evolution/session-bundle": "^1.0",
"twig/twig": "^1.0||^2.0"
},
"require-dev": {
"phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7.27",
"sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
"symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
},
"scripts": {
"symfony-scripts": [
"Incenteev\ParameterHandler\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
"Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
],
"post-install-cmd": [
"@symfony-scripts"
],
"post-update-cmd": [
"@symfony-scripts"
]
},
"config": {
"platform": {
"php": "5.6"
},
"sort-packages": true
},
"extra": {
"symfony-app-dir": "app",
"symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
"symfony-var-dir": "var",
"symfony-web-dir": "web",
"symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
"symfony-assets-install": "relative",
"incenteev-parameters": {
"file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
},
"branch-alias": {
"dev-master": "3.4-dev"
}
}
}

Someone has an idea please ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Also, are you sure this is in any way related to the package you want to add?

Comment: Hi Nico, I try to install spreadsheet bundle, with command : composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet:1.8.2 ... I tried composer install/update, and I got the same error, so it is not related to the package that I want to add

Comment: phpspreadsheet is not a bundle.  It is a library.  That is not just me being pedantic.  phpspreasheet has no symfony dependencies.  I don't think those errors are coming from trying to install phpspreadsheet.  I don't have a PHP 5.x environment handy but using PHP7.4 I created a fresh Symfony 5.2 project and then installed the library without a problem.  Maybe try making a fresh 3.4 project and then install phpspreadsheet without doing anything else and see what happens.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. I would assume that the error is related to `symfony/symfony replaces symfony/twig-bundle and thus cannot coexist with it` - as given in the error message itself

Comment: Thank's for your answers. @NicoHaase, yes but I don't know the origin of this error :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`symfony/symfony` is a package that contains **all** components of the Symfony framework. This also contains `symfony/twig-bundle`. There's no need to install both of these packages, so you can safely remove `symfony/twig-bundle`. Afterwards, it should be possible to add whatever package you want to add